# Custom uinavigatonbar exception

Tags: iphone, sdk, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've made a custom uinavigation bar this way:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navigation_background.png"];
        [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Now I'd like to add exception to show the normal uinavigation bar when i load an specific viewcontroller into de navigationcontroller.

How can I code that exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible with a category on `UINavigationBar`.
I would suggest a subclass, say `CustomNavigationBar`

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomNavigationBar : UINavigationBar {
}
@end
```

.m

```
#import "CustomNavigationBar.h"

@implementation CustomNavigationBar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navigation_background.png"];
        [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

The tricky thing is that you never create a `UINavigationBar` yourself, it's all handled by UIKit. To change the appearance of some bars only, you'll have to manually change their class at runtime.

Import

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

And in your view controller (in viewDidLoad for example), add

```
object_setClass(self.navigationController.navigationBar, [CustomNavigationBar class]);
```